# osx 10.9 monitor arrangement issue, laptop is the larger display

Tags: macos

Tiered of these strange issues, why my MacBook 10.9 ( started with .1 now I'm at .5 ) think that my laptop monitor is the external desktop monitor ?

The laptop has a high resolution and everything, and the desktop display has huge fonts .. 
This is not a signal issues or anything, i see both screens just fine.

(1)
When going to the System Preferences -> Display -> Arrangement, I click on the bigger-wide screen blue box and *both* monitors flash with red square. while clicking on the small blue box - only the desktop display has the red square ...

(2) At work - it works just fine, but at home ( Sumsung SyncMaster B2430 ) it happens...

Google didn't help ... 
I'll give it a shot here ... :/ thanks in advance.

Comment: http://chris.dziemborowicz.com/blog/2012/07/04/fix-external-monitor-resolution-on-macbook-pro-with-retina-display/ helped a little, maybe others will find this useful .. but to me the font height is stretching in a strange way ..

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the VGA cable entirely helped ... strange, because it works just fine on another PC ...
Read some post which says that Mac has some profile for every cable, changing the cable, creates a new profile.

Comment: Great that you found the answer yourself and that you're sharing it here. But... your answer is a bit short and difficult to understand. Could you elaborate what you did ("switching the VGA" is a bit vague)?